# Automatically add standard library to java file without IDE

Tags: java, ant

I have a lot autogenerated java file that contain only variables like this:

```
public class IdSome {

    public Date expDate;
    ..
    public String status;
    public Integer type;

    public IdSome(){
    }
}
```

And I use tast Ant that compile all these files:

```
<javac srcdir="C:/Customer" destdir="C:/CustomerBuild"/>
```

These files are not imported standard libraries for example for Date and therefore I can not compile this.

What can I do to add import without any IDE or/and add manually?

Comment: try with this, 
<target name="compile-tests">
  <javac executable="${javac1.6}" ...> ... </...>

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera Perhaps you should make your comment an Answer so it can be accepted and close this Question.

Comment: Auto-genertaed by what erroneous process? Fix the process and regenerate them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will work,
try with this,

```
<target name="compile-tests">
  <javac executable="${javac1.6}" ...> ... </...>
```